A Question about the Possibility of Transforming a Hyperbola into A Circle through Complex Geometry
I have been doing some questions where I can transform an ellipse
\begin{equation} \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \tag{1} , a>b>0, a>c>0\end{equation}
into a circle
\begin{equation} x^2 + y'^2 = a^2 \tag{2} \end{equation}
where I set
\begin{equation} y = \frac{b}{a} y' \tag{3} \end{equation}
Given this technique, I have been thinking about whether for a hyperbola
\begin{equation} \frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \tag{4} , c>a>0, b>0 \end{equation}
we can still transform it into a circle like $(2)$ or not, for example if we set
\begin{equation} y = \frac{b}{a} i y'' \tag{5} \end{equation}
then we have
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}- i^2 \frac{b^2 y''^2}{b^2 a^2} = 1$$
and this implies
\begin{equation} x^2 + y''^2 = a^2 \tag{6} \end{equation}
which is again a circle of radius $a$.
$\textbf{Question:}$ Now my question is, can we really do this transformation to conic sections in the real plane? I ask this, because the transformation $(5)$ is applying complex numbers to the real plane, and I don't know what will happen after that. Hope someone can help me explain this. Thanks!

In doing the ellipse-to-circle transformation, you could say "I'm transforming my coordinates. I'm going to let
$$
(u, v) = (x/a, y/b)
$$
and then my equation becomes
$$
u^2 + v^2 = 1,
$$
which is a circle, just with different coordinates."
Presumably you liked this coordinate transformation because it's easy to un-do. You'd hate something like
$$
(u, v) = (0, y)
$$
though, because if you could solve the $uv$-equation, you still couldn't figure out $x$. [This is an extreme and contrived example, of course.]
Presumably you'd also be OK with a substitution like
$$
(u, v) = (x + 5, y-3)
$$
to "simplify" some equation (again, because it's easily "undone"). The fancier way to say this is that you like "nonzero scaling" and "translation" as types of coordinate transformation. Combining sequences of these gets you even more operations. And you also start to realize that things like
$$
u = x \\
v = x + 3y
$$
are pretty benign (and undoable) as well.
The key thing about all of these is that if you know $(u, v)$, you can recover $(x, y)$, so they're just a way of shifting around the algebra a bit. They also all correspond to familiar operations on the plane, like stretching, sliding, shearing, rotation ... stuff we like and understand (mostly). If we call these "affine transformations", then we can say that "under affine transformations, any ellipse can be transformed to the unit circle."
There's another class of transformations on the plane, but they seem, to our eyes, to be deeply flawed: for certain $(x,y)$ pairs, the corresponding $(u, v)$ pair isn't even defined! Here's an example:
$$
u = \frac{x-2}{x-5}\\
v = y
$$
For $(x,y)$ pairs where $x = 5$, $u$ is undefined. Yikes! On the other hand, something wonderful has happened in disguise: suppose we let $x$ gradually get larger and larger. We see that $u \to 1$. So we could say that the $xy$-point $(\infty, 3)$ gets transformed to $(1, 3)$.
A more general version of this transformation is something like
$$
u = \frac{2x+ 3y-2}{x-y-5}\\
v = \frac{-x+ 4y+1}{x-y-5}
$$
With this transformation, any point on the line $x - y - 5$ can't be transformed, but if you "head out to infinity" along any particular ray, e.g., consider points $(x, y) = (3t, 5t)$, you find that as $t \to \infty$, the corresponding $uv$-values approach some limit.
This is the start of the lovely field called 'projective geometry', and things like the previous displayed equation are called 'projective transformations'. They are almost invertible, and we can say that "under projective transformations, any hyperbola can be transformed to the unit circle." (the same goes for parabolas)
Does that mean that in projective geometry there's really only one kind of conic? circles, parabolas, ellipses can all be thought of as just circles? Sort of. The second of these sentences is correct, but the first misses something. If you say that a "conic" is the set of solutions of some quadratic equation in $x$ and $y$, then there are a few more conics to consider:
$$
\text{(1). } x^2 + y^2 = -1
$$
That is (with real numbers, anyhow), an empty conic.
$$
\text{(2). } x^2 = 0
$$
This is the so-called "double line". If you look at $x(x + a) = 0$, whose solution set is the lines $x = 0$ and $x = -a$, then as $a$ approaches zero, you get two lines that get closer and closer, hence we call the limiting case a "doubled line".
$$
\text{(3). } xy = 0
$$
This is a pair of intersecting lines and it, too, cannot be transformed to a circle.
Are there others? That's a great question, and folks call it the problem of "classification of conics". (As you might guess, there are also classifications of higher-degree curves, too.) But that goes way beyond the question you asked.
BTW, the whole "gosh, these projective transformations don't really work" problem --- the fact that for certain $xy$-pairs, the transformation is undefined because of a division by zero --- is pretty unsettling. Once you sweep that under the rug, it feels as if you're really just fiddling with symbols that might not mean anything. Fortunately, there's a way out of this conundrum: instead of looking at the real plane, you look at a slightly larger set that has the real plane as one of its very large subsets in a kind of natural way.
Here's the deal. Take the ordinary $xy$-plane and lift it up the the $z = 1$ plane. So every point that used to have coordinates like $(3, 7)$ now has coordinates $(3, 7, 1)$. So far, this is a completely goofy transformation -- all it did was add a "1" to the end of each set of coordinates. We can "undo" it by removing the trailing "1". Cool.
Now let's take the point $(3, 7, 1)$ and draw a line from it to the origin $(0,0,0)$ in 3-space. We get a whole set of points, basically everything of the form
$(3t, 7t, 1t)$, where $t$ is any real number. We can do this more generally: for any $(x, y, 1)$ point, we can get a line-through-the-origin that contains it.
And for almost any line through the origin, we can find the intersection of that line with the $z = 1$ plane, so we almost have a 1-1 correspondence between "points of the plane" and "lines through the origin in 3-space". The only troublesome thing is that lines-through-the-origin that are horizontal (i.e., that lie entirely in the xy-plane) don't ever meet our $z = 1$ plane. So while our $z=1$ plane matches up nicely with lines-through-the-origin-in-3-space, it misses some of them.
On the other hand, it turns out that all the operations we did in the plane --- translation, rotation, scaling --- all correspond nicely to operations on this set of lines (which I'm going to start calling $P^2$ just to have a name). And if you carefully define notions of continuity, etc., on $P^2$, then even projective transformations make sense. If, as in our example above, a transformation is undefined at the point $(5, 1)$, which we now call $(5, 1, 1)$, which corresponds to a line $k$ from the origin through $(5,1,1)$, that transformation, when applied to the whole line $k$ turns out to produce a new line, $k'$ that's horizontal (i.e., its a point of $P^2$ that doesn't correspond to anything in the $z = 1$ version of the euclidean plane, but it's a perfectly good point of $P^2$).
This discovery -- that the euclidean plane could be embedded in a slightly larger space, $P^2$, in which "infinities" made some sense -- was a starting point for projective geometry. It's a pretty amazing mathematical trick: you have a function from $A$ to $B$ that's giving you troubles, and you ask "can we turn it into a function from $A'$ to $B'$, where $A'$ is a "slightly larger" version of $A$ (and similarly for $B'$), and then study this enlarged version?" (This is a little bit like what we do when we treat the real numbers as part of the larger set of complex numbers: suddenly equations that had no solutions, like $x^2 = -1$, now do have solutions!)
If all this intrigues you, I suggest that you take a peek at Robin Hartshorne's Introduction to Projective Geometry. It's an awful lot of fun.

Thanks for your comprehensive explanation on the whole stuffs. Yes, I am interested in what you have presented and I will take a look at the book you recommended. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Is the book actually called “ Foundations of Projective Geometry”?

Yes...thanks for catching this.
